# apparmor and Firefox

Tags: ubuntu, apparmor

I am currently re-setting up the `apparmor` profile for `Firefox 19.0.2` on `Ubuntu 12.04` and I am slightly confused. I must of had `Firefox 7.01` last time I used this and if I do `apparmor_status` then regarding firefox I get

```
..profiles are in enforce mode.
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}//browser_java
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}//browser_openjdk
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}//sanitized_helper
..profiles are in complain mode
/usr/lib/firefox-7.0.1/firefox.sh
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}//null-34
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}//null-34//null-35
..processes are in complain mode.
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]} (3818) 
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]} (17960) 
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]} (21817) 
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}//null-34 (3819) 
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}//null-34//null-35 (3823)
```

Now in the dir `/etc/apparmor.d/` the profiles I have in relation to firefox are
`usr.bin.firefox` and `usr.lib.firefox-7.0.1.firefox.sh`. Regarding the location of the firefox exec itself on my system - `/usr/bin/firefox` is a sym link to `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh` i.e. there is no version number.

Are these profiles in enforce mode some how sub profiles that are inheriting the parent profile and still in enforce mode despite the parent being in complain? Why is the profile shown in the status of the form `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox` not 1/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-7.01`?

Finally I thought messages were supposed to go to `/var/log/messages` yet this file does not exist for me, despite processes being left in complain mode for some time...

Comment: I'm really not sure I understand what your question is...

Comment: @Seth there are a few questions, 1)Given my firefox profile is in complain mode what are these profiles with things like `//browser_java` and what does this notation mean? (Is it some kind of sub profile/process of the firefox profile?). 2) From my directory structure, names and location of firefox, it looks like in `Ubuntu 12.04` one no longer needs to add the firefox version number to the profile, is this correct? 3) Why are my apparmor messages not going to `var/log/messages` ? (I've since discovered them in `kern.log`)

Answer (score 1):

These are "lenient" profiles for processes launched by firefox. The profile sanitized_helpers is defined in `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu_helpers`. There are others in `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-browsers.d/`
If the firefox profile contains this:

`/path/to/executable cx,`

then a child or local profile is used to confine "executable". The global profile for "executable" is used if the firefox profile contains this:

`/path/to/executable px,`

Yes, firefox version is not needed now.

If you install the `apparmor-notify` package, you will get desktop notifications whenever apparmor logs something to kern.log. Handy for debugging profiles.